# Android Debug Bridge(ADB) performance issues

Tags: android, adb

It is some time that we are experiencing performance issues with Android Debug Bridge on Mac. After few usages of the bridge it got stuck and takes a lot to perform any action. The only workaround we found to bring it to normal is to kill and restart the bridge, `adb kill-server && adb start-server`.

As an example after few usages of the tool, `adb devices` takes about ten seconds to execute while after a restart the result of the command is nearly immediate.

We have tried to reinstall and update ADB but the problem persists.

We experienced the problem on MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 with Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41; Version 31.0.3-7562133 and 31.0.2-7242960

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve or troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version. On Windows I have adb v33.0.0-8141338.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the suggestion. We have updated the tool to Version 33.0.0-8141338. The update seems to alleviate the problem but do not solve it completely